# RadioGroup in ScrollView does not fill ScrollView. Instead RadioButtons are squeezed

Tags: android, scrollview

If you have a larger amount of radio button in a RadioGroup and want them to stretch, instead of squeezed into small buttons, I thought of putting the RadioGroup in a ScrollView. However this does not work. Anyone an idea how to achieve this?

```
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >
    <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/news_radiogroup"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
      <RadioButton  />
      <RadioButton  />
      <RadioButton  />
      <RadioButton  />
      and more
   </RadioGroup>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `HorizontalScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`

Comment: That solves the problem. Didn't think about that, although somehow obvious. Thank you very much.